# How would I organize code in swift that is reused throughout multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently, I have two tableview that display the same information with some minor differences. These two different tableviews have separate view controllers and separate storyboards. I was wondering if there was a way to merge the similar code as well as storyboards together to create a more organized project.

Here is my code for the first view controller.

```
import UIKit

class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var GoalsTableView: UITableView!

var firstGoals: [String] = ["Read", "Write", "Think"]
var secondGoals: [String] = ["Run", "Go to the gym"]
var Goals: [String] = []
var valueToPass = ""
let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GoalsTableView.delegate = self
    GoalsTableView.dataSource = self
}

func showGoalSelected() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        let popUp = GoalSelectedPopUp()
        self.view.addSubview(popUp)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "activeGoalsSegue" {
    let viewController = segue.destination as! ActiveGoalsViewController
    viewController.Goals[0].append(valueToPass)
    }
}

}

extension GoalsOneViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Goals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalCell_1", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = Goals[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    valueToPass = Goals[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "activeFirstGoalsSegue", sender: self)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if Goals.count != 0 {
            Goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            showGoalSelected()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Goals"
}

}
```

Here is an image of the storyboard.
[image: Goals Storyboard]

How would I combine these two projects so that I only have one storyboard and one view controller?

Answer (score 1):

The way you can do this, is by making your ViewController more abstract. Instead of having array's like firstGoals and secondGoals, you can have just "goals". Using the goals array you can populate the ViewController. You can start by setting goals to equal an array called firstGoals that has your first goals in it i.e goals = firstGoals. Then whatever action the user takes to get to the second ViewController, like clicking a button, you can have it set up so that you can just set your goals array to the secondGoals array. Then reload the TableView by doing tableView.reloadData().

This will result in just one Storyboard and just one ViewController class.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code to match what I currently have. However, I am having difficulty changing the value based off of what the user selects. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @k-12345 You kind of have to give me a little more information. What specifically are you having trouble changing? What's the "value" and what is it the that user is selecting?

Comment: A holistic view of the program has a storyboard where the user can select to either do indoor or outdoor goals. After that selection, they are lead to a table view that presents them with specific goals in that respected category. From there the cell passes the "value" to a new tableview.

Comment: I am having trouble creating the array of goals for each respected section and then using them to fill the table view when that specific category is selected.

Comment: @k-12345 What you can do is on the screen where the user selects whether or not to do indoor or outdoor goals, before you segue into that screen, depending on which button is clicked, you pass a specific indoors or outdoors array to the array held in the GoalsViewController. If you have a general "goals" array in the GoalsViewController, then when you pass an array to that ViewController, it will populate automatically because you'll be populating the TableView from the data in the "goals" array, which you passed into the GoalsViewController before you segued.

Comment: @k-12345 The key is to have one "goals" array in the GoalsViewController, and before you go to the GoalsViewController, you populate that array depending on which button was clicked in the previous ViewController (either indoors or outdoors).